# shiny causes RStudio to crash

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

I am trying to use `shiny` for the first time. Every time when I am trying to run sample `shiny` app `RStudio` crashes with fatal error. The error which I am getting is :

```
Error in withCallingHandlers(tracatch(evalq(funtion (hash=TRUE, parent=parent.frame(), :
object '.rcpp_warning_recorder' not found.
```

I am using `R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)` -- "Pumpkin Helmet". Can someone please help?

Comment: You may want to run `update.packages()` occasionally.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try to reinstall **Rcpp**:

```
install.packages('Rcpp')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I reinstalled the package and it did work.

Comment: It is incredible to me how helpful this site is.  Whenever I type an error message into Google, it invariably leads me here to a solution.  Amazing.